# Server-to-Server App using Google Drive not responses to APIs calls

Tags: php, api, google-drive-api, server-to-server

I'm working on a project where I have to make a server to server app with **PHP**.

The concept is : the company uploads bills to Google drive and the users use the website to retrieve their bills. First of all I didn't use a composer to the server because I have no permission to install. So I downloaded the `libs` and uploaded to server with ftp. Then I created a `G Suite Google account` and followed the instructions from their guide https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts.

The weird thing is if `var_dump`(service) after `$results = $service->files` , I see that the verification for the client has be done. When I try to use the api with `$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);` the page doesn't respond. Im really confused with this.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
require 'init.php';

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=service.json');

$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

function getClient() {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    return $client;
}
 $optParams = array(
    'pageSize' => 5,
    'fields' => 'files(webViewLink, name , parents, id)'
);

$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
```

Comment: Could you provide the logs?

Comment: [06-Nov-2018 16:21:23 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/obiorange/public_html/nera/google-api-php-client-2.2.2/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php on line 84

Comment: i found that this error appears because 'class' is name of a constant , only PHP 5.5 doesnt use it as a tag . My PHP version is 5.6.30.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The problem was PHP version. I switched to 7.2 and seems to work perfect!